# Run 2.3.3 APP on 1.5 target

Tags: android, sdk

My app implemented on 2.3.3 version and I would like to run this app on 1.5 target . Is it possible?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

No, in most of the cases.

If your app is using any APIs that are introduced after 1.5 version, your app will not work.

It is always a good practice to implement your app for the oldest version possible.

For instance, if you are not using any APIs that are added after version 2.1, then it makes sense to implement your app in 2.1 version.

Hope this answered your question.